# How to get a container that I can call a type derived from the unique one by its index

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, memory

The problem. From I come here:

I have several template classes where the unique template argument is an 'unsigned char const'. The classes build a number with represetation with a radix B, which is the template argument. The template classes are derived from a concrete class:

```
class general_digit {

private:

// THE UNIQUE DATA MEMBER

   unsigned char m_d;

public:

// ALL THE PUBLIC METHODS

};

template<const unsigned char B>

class digit : public general_digit { 

private:

// I DON'T ADD ANY DATA

public:

// ALL THE PUBLIC METHODS

};
```

---

The problem. To where I want to go:

I'm making a parser/interpreter (an advanced calculator) with our types of numbers. The problem with the calculator is that the types are required in run-time, and with the required variables I can't select one of the 254 possibles types. There exists the posibility to write the code with a program, but I think that may exist a more satisfactory solution.

Comment: So the value of `B` varies at runtime? What are 'the 254 possible types' ?

Comment: The valor B is the radix of number, and B is too the template argument. From the calculator (run-time), the user will want a variable digit in any radix. Let **`nradix`** the variable of user that indicates the radix: I don't call _**`digit<nradix> newdigit;`**_. This is the cause of I want a container where for each index I find the variable of the adequate type. The 254 types are {digit<2>,digit<3>,...digit<254>,digit<255>}, the maximum radix is by the maximun value of a unsigned char. Does this commnets answer your asks?. Thanks.

Comment: what do you want to do with the `digit<B>` after you have selected it for a given value of `B`? Call a method on it? Create an instance of it that will be stored somewhere?

Comment: I'm going to try. I'm using flex/bison to make the calculator. Bison requires that for each ¿terminal? symbol I attach to it a type by the name into the %union of the some data member. When the user writes **`d#123#B131 A`** (digit 123 into the alphabet {0,1,2,...,130}) I have to recognize the type and instantiate the adequate variable A in a map, A is the key and the proper variable is the value type of the map (an indirect reference to a vector). If the number of the types were a few, wouldn't be problem. But the number of possible types dig_t<B> is the range of B, this is 0..255.Following..

Comment: As a function only can return solely one type I have a port in direct access to memory. The results are in the port (a vector where a position is of a specific type). I don´t get know how to resolve this. Thanks.